# php enforce type of extending class

Tags: php

Is there any way in php to make sure that a class can be extended by one and only one class?

I have some code that illustrates what I'm trying to do, basically I have a DB manager class and a DB query class that is extended by the manager class. What I'd like to do is make sure that the DB query class can only be used by the DB manager class.

The code below works, but it seems very rough. In the code I delcare the query class abstract with a single abstract function that checks the classname, or I could simply declare all of the Manager functions as abstract in the query class (which seems hacky). If there is a simpler way to do this than my code below that would be very useful...

```
abstract class DB_Query {

    private static $HOST = 'localhost';
    private static $USERNAME = 'guest';
    private static $PASSWORD = 'password';
    private static $DATABASE = 'APP';


//////////
/* USING ABSTRACT FUNCTION HERE TO ENFORCE CHILD TYPE */

abstract function isDB();

/* OR USING ALTERNATE ABSTRACT TO ENFORE CHILD TYPE */

    abstract function connect();
    abstract function findConnection();
    abstract function getParamArray();
//////////


    private function __construct() { return $this->Connect(); }
    public function Read($sql) { //implementation here }
    public function Query($sql) { //implementation here }
    public function Fetch($res, $type='row', $single='true') { //implementation here }

}

class DB extends DB_Query {

    public $connections = array();
    public static $instance;

    public function isDB() {
        if (get_parent_class() === 'Database' && get_class($this)!=='DB') {
            throw new \Exception('This class can\'t extend the Database class');
        }
    }

    public function connect($host=null,$user=null,$pass=null,$db=null) { //implementation here }
    function findConnection($user, $password=null) { //implementation here }
    public function getParamArray($param) {}
    public function threadList() {}
    public function getThread($threadId=null) {}
    public static function Singleton() { //implementation here }
    private function __construct() { //implementation here }

}
```

Comment: if it should only be extended by one class, it should not be extended at all.

Comment: if you build a framework you actualy do want more DB classes (one for mysql, one for mysqli, one for mssql etc). If you just build your own website you know isDB() will never throw (and so, is useless) and DB_Query will never be extended again because you wont build another child of DB_Query

Comment: What is this good for in practice? If you don't want certain classes to inherit something, **don't write them.** Who are you trying to protect against here? Also: no, it's not feasible. You're also violating the [SOLID principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: I split up my DB class into DB, DB_Connect, DB_Query for no other reason than for the sake of asbstraction, I found it helped clarify for my by making my classes discreet but what I don't want is someone to come behind me and use the DB_Query class not-through the DB class

Comment: Lets put it this way: this is not a problem that requires a solution in typical, well implemented OO program. You're either making things too complicated, are structuring your classes incorrectly or are worrying about the wrong things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go after marking the constructor of DB_Query as **final** and implementing it the way that it checks the instance and fires some exception. Something like this

```
class Base {
    final function __construct() {
         if (!$this instanceof Base && !$this instanceof TheChosenOne) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Only TheChosenOne can inherit Base");
         }

         /**
          * use this function as constructor
          */
         $this->__internal_base_construct();
    }

    protected function __internal_base_construct() {
     // constructor code
    }
}
```

But your problem is rather strange and kind of breaking the idea of OOP in several ways. Just combine it into a single class and use **final class** directive.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: what do you mean breaking the idea of OOP?

Comment: 1) For some reason a parent class needs to know something about its children. That's just wrong.

2) Creating a class that cannot be inherited is fine. But creating a class that can be inherited only by someone, that's just weird. OOP provides you with tools to protect methods, properties. Inheritance by itself is a substantial feature of OOP that cannot be just ripped off.

Comment: short of combining into a single class, and instead of extending, would you use aggregation or composition in this case?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've found out that you can't use final and private at the same time as in final private __construct() because it can't be extended that way, so my now singleton base class is not a singleton as long as I'm verifying type, But, this is by far the best solution I've see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Database_Query extends Database {

    public static $instance;
    public function Query($sql) {}
    public function Fetch($res, $type='row', $single='true') {}
    public static function Singleton() {}

    private function __construct() {
        $this->link = $this->connect()->find('guest')->getLink();
    }

}
```